Debugging an ASP.Net Core sub application under ASP .NET Root App when running in IIS Express
I have an ASP.NET (MVC 5 and .NET Framework 4.7.2) Application in IIS Express 10, as Root App and several others with the same framework as sub applications. This setup works as expected. Sample IIS Express applicationhost.config.
<site name="web_site_01" id="1">
 <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
   <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\c\Root\WebApp" />
 </application>
 <application path="/subbapp01" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
  <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\c\subbapp01\WebApp" />
  </application>
 <application path="/subbapp02" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
  <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\c\subbapp02\WebApp" />
 </application>
 <bindings>
  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:5000:localhost" />
  <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:5001:localhost" />
 </bindings>
</site>

Now, I am trying to run an ASP.NET Core 8.0 WebAPI as a sub application under this Root application using in-process hosting.
I have managed to make the application running properly in this setup, using a No-Managed Application pool. The modified applicationhost.config is like below
 <applicationPools>
  <add name="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
  <add name="NoManagedApi_subappNetCore01" managedRuntimeVersion="" />
  <applicationPoolDefaults managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
    <processModel loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="false" />
  </applicationPoolDefaults>
</applicationPools>
<sites>
 <site name="web_site_01" id="1">
  <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\c\Root\WebApp" />
  </application>
  <application path="/subapp01" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
   <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\c\subapp01\WebApp" />
   </application>
  <application path="/subapp02" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
   <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\c\subapp02\WebApp" />
  </application>
  <application path="/subappNetCore01" applicationPool="NoManagedApi_subappNetCore01">
   <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\c\subappNetCore01\Api" />
  </application>
  <bindings>
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:5000:localhost" />
   <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:5001:localhost" />
  </bindings>
 </site>
</sites>

However, what does not work, is the debugging experience in Visual Studio 2022 17.8.
When I start debugging using the Root project as startup, The Debugger does not load automatically for the ASP.Net Core app. Also I cannot attach it since the process is under IIS Express, which is properly being debugged by VS. So, I cannot debug the ASP.NET Core Application.
If I try to run the Core app using the out-of process hosting model, it launches as a proper application but on a different port than the root app, thus defeating the original specification of running under a Root App.
The web.config of the ASP.NET Core 8.0 app is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <connectionStrings>
      <clear />
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
      <clear />
    </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <remove name="aspNetCore" />
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet"
                  arguments=".\bin\Debug\net8.0\subappNetCore01.dll"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="true"
                  stdoutLogFile="c:\temp\logs\stdout" 
                  hostingModel="inprocess" >
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
      <modules>
        <!-- Remove All managed modules because app pool is "no managed" -->
        <remove name="OutputCache" />
        <remove name="Session" />
        <remove name="WindowsAuthentication" />
        <remove name="DefaultAuthentication" />
        <remove name="RoleManager" />
        <remove name="UrlAuthorization" />
        <remove name="FileAuthorization" />
        <remove name="AnonymousIdentification" />
        <remove name="Profile" />
        <remove name="UrlMappingsModule" />
        <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
        <remove name="ScriptModule-4.0" />
        <remove name="HtmlMinificationModule" />
        <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
        <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
        <!-- Remove Incompatilbe native modules -->
        <remove name="CustomErrorModule" />
        <remove name="DefaultDocumentModule" />
        <remove name="DirectoryListingModule" />
        <remove name="FileCacheModule" />
        <remove name="HttpCacheModule" />
        <remove name="ServerSideIncludeModule" />
        <remove name="StaticCompressionModule" />
        <remove name="StaticFileModule" />
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
      </modules>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 7d3ad76a-f767-4d6f-a7b8-b61b422076c0-->

In Program.cs of the ASP.NET Core app, I use
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
builder.WebHost.UseIIS();
var app = builder.Build();
...
app.UsePathBase("/subappNetCore01");
...
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

I have tried having a web.config in ASP.NET core App, using the out of process model, using the Core App as start up in VS both alone and in combination with my Root app.
All in hope of either starting the debugger automatically or get a handle to attach it to but to no avail.
Is this setup possible or am I missing something ?

IIS Express is there for the simplest setup such as single application hosting and troubleshooting. If you need to combine several projects together, install local IIS and enable VS IIS development time support.

As Lex li said you could use iis to host the both root and sub application as shown below:
1)Create website and deploy your root mvc site:

2)Under that site create Application and use your web api published path:

Create separate pool for this application and while creating app choose that app pool from the list.

3)Now run your web site or application in the browser
4)Go to the visual studio->  Debug-> Select Attach to process

5)Check "Show processes for all users"
In the search look for the w3wp.exe
6)From the list select your sub application worker process and click Attach:

Set the break point and debug your application as needed.
